# NOT bitwise operator breaks unsigned integers?

Tags: c, types, bit-manipulation, unsigned-integer

I am trying to have C interpret an inverted unsigned integer as an unsigned integer.  **How can I invert the bits of a unsigned number without C interpreting it as two’s complement?**

Whenever I have an unsigned integer and I use it as a operand with the bitwise NOT operator it evaluates to a negative number as according to two’s complement.  However by definition **I am using an unsigned integer, a number that should not have a sign**.

Below has my sandboxed code. I am currently using GCC version 9.1.1.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(){
   uint8_t x = 1;//0000 0001
   printf("NOT(%d) == %d", x, ~x);//1111 1110
}
```

I want the output of 254 (1111 1110) but C interprets the value as two’s complement so I get -2.  Is there a way I can get C to **not** interpret the inverted byte as two’s complement?

Comment: You're telling it to interpret the number as signed with "%d". Use "%u".

Comment: Actually that's undefined behaviour because of format specifier not matching type provided, additionally size doesn't match as well... Most likely, `uint8_t` would require `%hhu` format specifier; safer is to use the appropriate macros from [`<inttypes.h>` header](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer).

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker: That will print 4294967294 or some similar value corresponding to the `unsigned int` width (`UINT_MAX-1`), not the 254 that the question seeks.

Comment: @Aconcagua: There is no undefined behavior from the format specifier. The integer promotions automatically promote `x` to `int`, so the arguments `x` and `~x` both have type `int`, which is the proper type to format with `%d`.

Comment: See [Implicit type promotion rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules).

Comment: And btw even without the ~ causing integer promotion, variadic functions integrate promote their parameters anyway. So it is literally impossible to pass a `char` to printf. The best you can do is to tell printf to treat the passed `int` as `char`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C, when an integer narrower than an `int` is used in an expression, it is automatically promoted to `int`. Thus, in `~x`, the `uint8_t` is automatically converted to an `int`, and then the bitwise `~` is performed, and then the result is passed to `printf` as an `int`. So what is printed is the result of inverting all the bits of an `int`, instead of just the bits of a `uint8_t`.

To get a `uint8_t` result, cast the expression to `uint8_t`:

```
printf("NOT(%d) == %d", x, (uint8_t) ~x);
```

Note that after the `uint8_t` conversion is performed, the value is again automatically promoted to an `int`, so `printf` receives an `int` in either case. However, the conversion reduces the value to one representable in a `uint8_t`, and this is the value that will be printed.

However, the conversion to `uint8_t` is using an `int` as the source type, so the bits of `~x` will be interpreted according to the implementation’s `int` format. To get the low bits of `~x` without relying on the `int` format, you can extract them with `& 0xff` instead of using a cast:

```
printf("NOT(%d) == %d", x, ~x & 0xff);
```

Alternately, you can perform the bitwise `~` on an `unsigned` value instead of an `int` value:

```
printf("NOT(%d) == %d", x, (uint8_t) ~ (unsigned) x);
```

Comment: This relies on the system using 2's complement for `int` . The result would be different for ones complement for example. You could avoid that dependency with `(uint8_t)~(unsigned)x` perhaps

Comment: @chux moot point for `uint8_t` since it is unsigned , conceivably the system could offer `int8_t` with some hoop-jumping for any operations involving that type. But yes, probably such a system never exists.

Comment: @M.M True again.